# Select nearest location and one that is a little further away in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to select from a table of locations. The result should be the closest location and additionally a location that is at least 30km distance away.

So i'm trying to do a

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE (distance = minimumdistance OR distance > 30) AND some other parameters LIMIT 2
```

But i can't get the min distance without a second select that has all the other parameters too which will make the statement massively long.

MIN(distance) needs a grouping but that would result in me getting only one result instead of 2...

Is there any way to do this more simple? Create the statement without having the full WHERE clause two times within the statement.

Currently it's

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE (distance = (SELECT MIN(distance) FROM locations WHERE some other parameters ) OR distance > 30) AND some other parameters LIMIT 2
```

now try to imagine that with some other parameters beeing a pretty long string and distance beeing a calculation instead of a static table column and this becomes pretty nasty.

Comment: Not completely sure I understand your question -- might help to have your table structure, sample data and desired results...

Comment: `massively long` makes no sense.  Massive relates to mass, not length. What exactly do you mean? Your statement would be well within the max limits for SQL statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on doing it in one query, then this will do as you need (updated to be more standard)

```
SELECT

        -- this will have 2 records, 1 nearest and 1 with l.distance > 30
        d.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        loc.*,
        -- this assumes locationID == the PK field, update as needed
        IF(loc.distance>30,@farLoc := loc.locationID,@nearLoc := loc.locationID) AS ignoreMe
    FROM locations AS loc,
    (
        SELECT @nearLoc := 0,@farLoc := 0
    ) AS v
    WHERE some other parameters
    ORDER BY loc.distance DESC 
) AS d
WHERE d.locationID IN (@nearLoc,@farLoc)
```

But really simple union will do what you should use in this instance

```
(
    SELECT * FROM locations 
    WHERE some other parameters
    ORDER BY distance ASC 
    LIMIT 1
) UNION (
    SELECT * FROM locations 
    WHERE some other parameters
    AND distance > 30 
    ORDER BY distance ASC 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

It doesn't really matter if the statement is "massively long" so long as it is efficient.  If the other parameters are generated within a script then it's no extra overhead to maintain and this will be the most efficient method.

Comment: Your first query depends on the use of column in the group by coming from the first record.  MySQL documentation is quite explicit that this assumptino is not valid:  "However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate." (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: The ORDER BY DISTANCE within the subquery ensures that the nearest and the nearest with distance > 30 are chosen.  The external GROUP will result in the first record for each matching value of isNear.  There are no group functions being used in the parent query and so the l.* will return the correct data.  Additional criteria can be added to the subquery WHERE/ORDER to further control this.

Comment: Not according to the documentation.  It might work in practice, but the documentation explicitly states that you cannot dependon this behavior.

Comment: The UNION would be my preferred method of these two as I tried to clearly state, but the original post stated a reluctance to do that.  This may not be standard SQL but it will function as intended within MySQL.  Could probably make a version that is SQL standard however would likely be less efficient.  UNION is really the way to go.

Comment: There, that final update *should* be more standard, removes the reliance on a  GROUP however I still vastly prefer the UNION method

Comment: Ok we solved this actually with this answer, we had an syntax error on the UNION statement that caused the ORDER BY to malfunction on the first try forcing us (at least we thought so) to use the select within the select.

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

```
    SELECT * FROM locations WHERE  some other parameters 
    HAVING  distance > 30
    OR distance = minimumdistance 
    LIMIT 2
```

Comment: The result should be the closest location AND one that is at least 30km distance away. Shouldn't you write an AND operator instead of OR?

Comment: And how do i get the distance of the nearest result? That's the main problem here, how to calculate the minimumdistance.

Comment: you have writed `distance = minimumdistance OR distance > 30` thats why , but you can try with AND.

Comment: Yeah i want the location that is closest AND one additional location that is further away (at least 30km)... that's why the OR, but it still doesn't solve how to calculate the minimum distance without duplicating the full where clause

Comment: `how to calculate the minimum distance`. Do you really mean `calculate`? Is `distance` a column or a value you must calculate?

Comment: better give some sample data of your tables and the wished result .

Answer (score 0):

I am not thrilled with this method, but it should work in MySQL:

```
select l.*
from (SELECT l.*, (@rn = @rn+1) as rn
      FROM locations l cross join
           (select @rn = 0)
      WHERE some other parameters
      order by distance
     ) l
where rn = 1 or distance > 30
limit 2
```

@rn is a variable that keeps track of the row number.  In most other databases, you would use `row_number()`, but that is not supported by MySQL.  It then chooses either the first row (minimum distance) or one greater than 30.  If the minimum is greater than 30, then you will get two rows.

In practice, it will return the closest under 30.

Answer (score 0):

`The result should be the closest location and additionally a location that is at least 30km distance away`

Does this work in mySQL? It works in SQLite:

```
     select min(distance) from foo
     where distance > (select min(distance) from foo) and distance > 30
     union 
     select min(distance) from foo
```

If it does work, you could use it to create an inline view and do this:

```
     select name, min(dist) from
     (

     select name, dist
     from   foo
     join
     (
     select min(distance) as dist from foo 
     where distance > (select min(distance) from foo) and distance > 30
     union 
     select min(distance) as dist from foo  
     ) as X         
     on foo.distance = X.dist   

   )

   union

    select name, max(dist) from

    (

     select name, dist
     from   foo
     join
     (
     select min(distance) as dist from foo 
     where distance > (select min(distance) from foo) and distance > 30
     union 
     select min(distance) as dist from foo  
     ) as X         
     on foo.distance = X.dist   

   )
```

With an index on column [distance] this would be very fast.